# how to Kill hadoop task started using hadoop jar command?

Tags: hadoop

I'm pretty new to using Hadoop.

I used hadoop jar command like the one below -

```
hadoop jar $jarpath/BDAnalytics.jar \
   bigdat.twitter.crawler.CrawlTwitter \
   $crwlInputFile  > $logsFldr/crawler_$1.log 2>&1 &
```

But I need to kill this process, and not able to understand how.
There are a lot of links to kill hadoop jobs but since this is not a job but a task/java process.

I will high appreciate if you could let me know the command to kill such a process.
Thanks in advance!
-RG

Comment: You need to kill the hadoop program but leave all the nodes up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the shell command `kill`. For example, use `ps -ef | grep bigdat.twitter.crawler.CrawlTwitter` to find the pid, and use `kill -9 pid_of_the_process` to kill it. You can write a script containing the following command to do the kill action:

```
#!/bin/bash    
kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep bigdat.twitter.crawler.CrawlTwitter | sed "s/\s\+/\t/g" | cut -f2)
```